# Create new column with coordinates from centroids using st_transform in PostGIS / PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, postgis

I have geometry data that I'm trying to transform to lon lat and store in a new column. I have created a new column called 'coordinates' and written the following query:

```
UPDATE places_centroids
SET coordinates = st_y(st_transform(new_centroid, 4326)) AS lat,
st_x(st_transform(new_centroid, 4326)) AS lon;
```

But it returns: ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near
LINE 2: ...coordinates = st_y(st_transform(new_centroid, 4326)) AS lat,

However, it works fine when i writing the query with a select statement:

```
SELECT st_y(st_transform(new_centroid, 4326)) AS lat,
         st_x(st_transform(new_centroid, 4326)) AS lon
FROM places_centroids;
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with my query?

Comment: What column type is coordinates?

Comment: Remove the `as ..` parts, they are invalid in the SET clause

Comment: It's double precision. Alright, but how would I do it without 'as'?

Comment: How would you store two values into one `double precision` column?

Comment: That's true wildplasser.. But what if I create two columns, one to contain lat and one to contain lon?

Comment: @johnny keep these points in one single column of type geometry or geography. In most cases it's a bad idea to split them in separated numeric columns. Welcome to Stack Overflow and happy holidays :)

Comment: First of all, thank you Bjarni! It worked out very well. Secondly, the geometry type works well when using PostGIS and QGIS etc., but I the database is connected to R, and as far as I know, it's not possible to read geometry type data with RPostgreSQL. That's why I wanted to transform the data. Happy holidays to all of you, and thank you Jim Jones!

Comment: @Johnny R can read WKT or GeoJSON, so I guess all you need is to convert it in your query, e.g. with st_astext(geom)

Comment: Alright, @JimJones, that might be a better solution? I will try it, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two columns, lat and lng for example of type double precision and do this:

```
UPDATE places_centroids 
SET lat = st_y(st_transform(new_centroid, 4326)),
lng= st_x(st_transform(new_centroid, 4326));
```

or define coordinates as the native point type:

```
UPDATE places_centroids
SET coordinates = point(st_y(st_transform(new_centroid, 4326)),
st_x(st_transform(new_centroid, 4326)));
```

I personally prefer to store in two columns.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Why do you prefer to have point coordinates in two columns? Aren't the PostGIS functions designed for geometry typed columns?

Comment: I use Postgis, not the native Postgres geometry types and functions.  Most data, public data for instance, uses lat and lng so it's convenient to have those. I usually also have the third column of Postgis type geometry point.  It is not the same as native point type.

Comment: No need to use the native `point` since there is already the `new_centroid` geometry column in the OP table